# Updating information into database deletes some when updates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form to update a users profile and have used some PHP code to check if a field is empty or not, if its not the field does not display but it wipes out the information in that field in the database. How would I stop this from happening?

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
                if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
                echo 'Your details have been updated!';
                } else {
                if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {

                    $update_data = array(
                        'aboutme'       => $_POST['aboutme'],
                        'facebook'      => $_POST['facebook'],
                        'twitter'       => $_POST['twitter'],
                        'google'        => $_POST['google'],
                        'linked'        => $_POST['linked'],
                        'pokerstars'    => $_POST['pokerstars'],
                        'pokerstarsfr'  => $_POST['pokerstarsfr'],
                        '888poker'      => $_POST['888poker'],
                        'fullflush'     => $_POST['fullflush'],
                        'partypoker'    => $_POST['partypoker'],
                    );

                update_user($session_user_id, $update_data);
                header('Location: settings.php?success');
                exit();

                } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
                    echo output_errors($errors);
                }
            }
            ?>
```

And here is the form code:

```
<form class="margin-bottom-40" role="form" method="post" action="">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>About Me</label><br>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" name="aboutme"><?php echo $user_data['aboutme']; ?></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Facebook</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="facebook" placeholder="Please start with www." value="<?php echo $user_data['facebook']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Twitter</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="twitter" placeholder="Please start with www." value="<?php echo $user_data['twitter']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Google+</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="google" placeholder="Please start with www." value="<?php echo $user_data['google']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>LinkedIn</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="linked" placeholder="Please start with www." value="<?php echo $user_data['linked']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user_data['email']; ?>" name="email">

                        <h3>Poker ID's</h3>
                        Please note: You can only enter your poker ID once, after this it can NOT be changed.<br><br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>PokerStars ID</label> 
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user_data['pokerstars']; ?>" name="pokerstars" <?php if(!empty($user_data['pokerstars'])) { echo 'disabled'; } ?> >
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>PartyPoker ID</label> 
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user_data['partypoker']; ?>" name="partypoker" <?php if(!empty($user_data['partypoker'])) { echo 'disabled'; } ?> >
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Full Flush Poker ID</label> 
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user_data['fullflush']; ?>" name="fullflush" <?php if(!empty($user_data['fullflush'])) { echo 'disabled'; } ?> >
                        </div>
                        <?php if (empty($user_data['888poker'])): ?>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label>888 Poker ID</label>
                            <input type="text" name="888poker" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user_data['888poker']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if (empty($user_data['pokerstarsfr'])): ?>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label>PokerStars.fr ID</label>
                            <input type="text" name="pokerstarsfr" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <br><br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-u">Update!</button>
                    </form>
```

I have tried several ways as you can see from the different types of php code in the form but no luck as yet.

Answer (score 2):

When you set a form field as **disabled**, it will be not even sent to the server. If you want just to prevent the user from editting the field, you should use **readonly** instead.

### Edit:

Also, if you don't want the user to change the value, you MUST ensure the value is not changed on the server-side. It's realy easy to remove the `readonly` attribute from the field.

Comment: That actually won't solve the problem because he will still be setting it to blank

Comment: if you var_dump the $update_data right before updating user, you'll see that those indexes still exist in the array, but are undefined

Comment: I agree that the information is not sent to $_POST, but that is not the issue. See, if you look at the code, he is setting the $update_data to have those indexes regardless of whether or not its in the $_POST. But, by setting those indexes, then he is updating the user to have that property of NULL

Comment: But when you use readonly instead of disabled, the information **will** be sent. I don't see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Change the $update_data part of your code to the following:

```
$update_data = array();                
$update_array = array(
                    'aboutme',
                    'facebook',
                    'twitter',
                    'google',
                    'linked',
                    'pokerstars',
                    'pokerstarsfr',
                    '888poker',
                    'fullflush',
                    'partypoker')
);
foreach($update_array as $social) {
    if(!empty($_POST[$social])) {
        $update_data[$social] = $_POST[$social];
    }
}
```